# How can I reflect a Resource String in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Say, I got a Resource String defined in my data.pas, like below

```
unit data
interface
ResourceString
    res_TEST = 'THIS IS MY RESOURCE STRING';
implementation
end.
```

How can I get this resource by using string "res_TEST" just like the reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No RTTI information is generated for resource strings. There is no way to use reflection to access the resource string by name.

Comment: Just for backing up Davids answer you can test it you self with this example
http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1710